# Are season passes no longer downloaded on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

Previously, for instance for Battlefield 4, you had to download the season pass for the game to recognise your rights to the extra dlc's.

For both Fallout 4 and The Division (which arguably hasn't come out yet) I bought the big packages that included the season pass.

I can see the season pass in the store for both the games, but it won't download, but the rest of the miniature dlc's for the games are installed.

If I select the season pass for Fallout 4 and pick "Administrate", an empty page comes up, save for my profile info top left. For the Division season pass (again, I know it hasn't been released yet) there isn't even an "Administrate" option.

Are season passes no longer required to be downloaded on Xbox One? Is there some known information about this?

I know there isn't any content that has been released for those with the season pass yet but I'd rather find out that there is a problem now than the day the content is dropped.

Comment: While I'm not really sure, considering how big updates come out for XB1, I'd guess that they found a better way for it.

Comment: All three of those games are different publishers are they not? Maybe that's just an EA thing?